# Why is truncation handled differently between convolution and cross-correlation?

Tags: integration, convolution

In [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition), the indefinite bounds of the integration are truncated from $0$ to $t$.

In [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Cross-correlation_of_deterministic_signals), the indefinite bounds of the integration are truncated to one period of a periodic function.

Since convolution and cross-correlation are adjoint operators, why is there a difference in how the bounds are truncated?

Comment: This all comes down to their **definition**s. Cross-correlation is a measure of _similarity_ between two signals. So if they are periodic, naturally we just measure the similarity in one period. On the other hand, convolution is a measure of the combined effect of signals. See [this excellent thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/5892/93602) for an intuitive explanation. So for causal signals, the limits are truncated to the interval between $0$ and $t$ by simply letting $s(t)=0$ for $t<0$.